# Genymotion quits in MAC OS 10.11.5

Tags: genymotion

Anybody faced the below issue with Genymotion while running on MAC OS 10.11.5.

Installed version: Genymotion 2.7.2, VirtualBox 5.0.24
[Please click here to view the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liwwz.png)